# Upload to a Share point site

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

Let me share the following scenario:

I have a ASP.NET intranet Web-based application that generates Excel reports on server. I want to drop this reports on a Share point portal where this report can be viewed by all users. What all do I need to achieve this through ASP.NET? The SharePoint portal is obviously hosted on another server.

Thanx in advance and a million apologies if this is a dumb question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Out-of the box Webservice, `_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` in SharePoint. Add a web reference to that webservice in your asp.net web site project and use that to add list items (files) to a list.

P.S. There are no "dumb" questions. There is a lot of information to be found on this subject on the web though...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/314258/how-do-i-upload-a-document-to-sharepoint-with-java/314477 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787610/how-do-you-copy-a-file-into-sharepoint-using-a-webservice for examples.

Answer (score 0):

How about putting all these reports on a shared folder and setting respective sharing permissions on the folder in sharepoint?

Does this work?

Comment: So u mean to say I need to control this from SharePoint but that would be against company policy as it gives facility to upload files to different user departments. Also I am a newbie to SharePoint and have no knowledge of its working.

Comment: See if your company already have any sharepoint folders that are accessible by everyone (public share). If there are, you can use one of those as target folders.  If there aren't any, I would suggest you speak with your functional manager/team lead to resolve the issue and get his directions on this.